# I get an {"Index was outside the bounds of the array."} error when trying to terminate a program through Speech Recognition

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I followed a speech recognition tutorial about opening and closing program. when I execute a command to open MS WORD it does fine but when I try to close the program I get an error message regarding the index was outside the bound of the array. It points to the Procs[0] as being out of bounds.

```
     public static void killProg(string s)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] Procs = null;

        try
        {
            Procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(s);
            Process prog = Procs[0];

            if (!prog.HasExited)
            {
                prog.Kill();

            }
        }

        finally
        {
            if (Procs != null)
            {
                foreach (Process p in Procs)
                {
                    p.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

Can anybody help? I'm very new to using C# and not sure what to do?

Answer (score 0):

`Procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(s);` is probably returns 0 elements. Which leads `Procs[0];` to throw `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Protect your code against the possibility of which you will not find what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `Process.GetProcessesByName(s)` call returns an empty array, which means there is no first element (index 0) and hence you get an exception.

You should check if the array is not empty:

```
Procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(s);
if ( Procs.Length > 0 )
{
   //your code
}
```